# Struggling to make Bootstrap-select to work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap-select (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and cannot make it load any options. It renders the dropbox but not the options. I'm a little bit lost and not sure if I'm loading the proper dependencies in the proper order or doing something stupid.

I'm starting to learn all that stuff and might be doing something wrong in here. I've created a plunker so I can clearly reproduced the issue.

Appreciate any help!

This is my code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/f80WGOjxuxBfXomOgEZn?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script src="script.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">  

     <!-- Jquery javascript version 1.12.4 -->
     <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <!--script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script-->

     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS for Bootstrap-select-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript for Bootstrap-select -->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

     <!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>

  </head>

 <body onload="start()">
   <h1>Bootstrap-select Dropdown test!</h1>

   <select class="selectpicker">
     <option>Mustard</option>
     <option>Ketchup</option>
     <option>Relish</option>
   </select>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should load your javascript at the end of your `body`. And for sure you have to add a language instead of `*` in `defaults-*.min.js`

Comment: @makshh he does it in the `script.js` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the bootstrap js in your html.

Here we go: https://plnkr.co/edit/JZhBHwTooRVVDpVYb8u0?p=preview

All you needed was just

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Remember to put your js files *at the end* of your `body` and that **any custom file has to be loaded after** the libraries, to let you call functions from them and be able to override their things.

That's why the final js part should be

```
<!-- rest of body here -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/i18n/defaults-en_US.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<!-- close body & html -->
```